# Is .htaccess necessary for Apache httpd?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd, htaccess

I'm now setting up a weblog site and encountered this problem.

My server is Apache httpd 2.2. In case my weblog pollutes the root directory(`htdocs`), I created a subdirectory `blog`. The current state is that I can access the root directory from outside with `http://my_ip_address/`; it shows `It works.`.

However, when I access the URL `http://my_ip_address/blog`, the server does not respond. I think there must be something wrong with the configuration. After searching Google, I find `.htaccess` may be the point, which is missing in the `blog` directory. Am I on the right track? By the way, what does `.htaccess` used to do?

Could you please give me a reference as a starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) is used for setting access to a site. its not what you need - you need to look at [mod rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or vhosts and setting the [vhost document r](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)oot to /var/www/blog

the best starting point, naturally is apache's own docs, which i have linked to

Comment: You use a lot of those rewrite directives in `.htaccess` files as well, if they only need to be directory specific, as your link shows.

Answer (score 3):

.htaccess isn't usually *required*.   It is used for configuration directives that might otherwise need to be put in the httpd.conf file, and is especially useful in cases where you don't have access to the server configuration.

At any rate, that probably isn't your problem.  I suggest you review your httpd-error.log to see if the problem might be listed there.